# Returning a functions output inside flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I would like to return the output of a function called to start inside my flask render profile function.

The code explains better than I do:

```py
# Creates the profile page for users, the users are required to be logged in to view this page
@main.route('/profile')
@login_required
def profile():
    output = getpass()
    #this function returns 13, 17, 22 and 25 
    if getpass() != None:
        print("output")
        return render_template('profile.html', name=current_user.name, email=current_user.email, id=output)
    else:
        print("nothing here"
        return render_template('profile.html', name=current_user.name)
```

```html
{% if id is defined %}
<h1>
  {% for i in id %}
    Your ID are: {{ id }}
  {% endfor %}
</h1>
{% endif %}
```

The website however does not show anything and unfortunately it prints nothing here in the terminal. How do I return the output from the function properly to make website show the IDs?

Comment: `print("nothing here"` I believe you forgot something on this line

Comment: `{% if id is defined %}` Is `defined` a variable you don't show us? if not, that is an invalid condition.

Comment: Considering my previous 2 comments, you should verify that the flask app is starting without any errors in the terminal.

Comment: The flask application does work, the end parentheses is fixed. When I try to print output, it prints None, so there might be something wrong with the getpass function.

Comment: maybe first use `print(output)` to see what you get. And if I know `getpass()` returns string so comparing with `None` can be wrong.

Comment: you should run `getpass()` only once - and later check `output != None`. At this moment it run it two times. First `output = getpass()` and again `if getpass() != None` so it may gives two different values.

Comment: to run this `getpass()` you would have to first open page `/profile` in browser.